# Run bitcoind with bitcoind.conf in docker

Tags: docker, bitcoin

I know docker, but less about bitcoind.
Now I want to use [this](https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-bitcoind) docker image to start my own test environment:
The description tells me:

```
docker volume create --name=bitcoind-data
 docker run -v bitcoind-data:/bitcoin --name=bitcoind-node -d \
     -p 8333:8333 \
     -p 127.0.0.1:8332:8332 \
     kylemanna/bitcoind
```

Now I want to now how I have to add my bitcoind.conf?
This isn't provided anywere? Can I use it at container startup or `docker exec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository contains a documentation file dedicated to your issue: https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-bitcoind/blob/master/docs/config.md

Comment: I tried: `docker run -v bitcoind-data:/bitcoin --name=bitcoind-node -d \
        -p 18333:18333 \
        -p 127.0.0.1:18332:18332 \
        -v /path/to/bitcoin.conf:/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf \
        kylemanna/bitcoind -testnet `

it works, the cli is telling me I'm connected with the testnet but I don't see any log and data coming in. I only see a cat of my configfile

Comment: AFAIK the log will be written to a `debug.log` in the bitcoin directory. Argument `-printtoconsole` tells bitcoind to log to the console instead.